# Is it possible to generate ansi C functions with type information for a moving GC implementation?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, garbage-collection, c99

I am wondering what methods there are to add typing information to generated C methods. I'm transpiling a higher-level programming language to C and I'd like to add a moving garbage collector. However to do that I need the method variables to have typing information, otherwise I could modify a primitive value that looks like a pointer.

An obvious approach would be to encapsulate all (primitive and non-primitive) variables in a struct that has an extra (enum) variable for typing information, however this would cause memory and performance overhead, the transpiled code is namely meant for embedded platforms. If I were to accept the memory overhead the obvious option would be to use a heap handle for all objects and then I'd be able to freely move heap blocks. However I'm wondering if there's a more efficient better approach.

I've come up with a potential solution, namely to predeclare and group variables based whether they're primitives or not (I can do that in the transpiler), and add an offset variable to each method at the end (I need to be able to find it accurately when scanning the stack area), that tells me where the non-primitive variables begin and where they end, so I can only scan those. This means that each method will use an additional 16/32-bit (depending on arch) of memory, however this should still be more memory efficient than the heap handle approach.

Example:

```
void my_func() {
  int i = 5;
  int z = 3;
  bool b = false;
  void* person;
  void* person_info = ...;
  .... // logic
  volatile int offset = 0x034;
}
```

My aim is for something that works universally across GCC compilers, thus my concerns are:

- Can the compiler reorder the variables from how they're declared in
  the source code?
- Can I force the compiler to put some data in the
  method's stack frame (using volatile)?
- Can I find the offset accurately when scanning the stack?

I'd like to avoid assembly so this approach can work (by default) across multiple platforms, however I'm open for methods even if they involve assembly (if they're reliable).

Comment: You might consider adding a "section" attribute to group them according to "type" (i.e. the section name is the "type"): `int foo __attribute__((section("type_a")));` and `int bar __attribute__((section("type_b")));`. You could compile with `-S` to get the `.s` file, use a script on it to do whatever you need. See my answer from a few minutes ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61648512/5382650 and another for grouping according to section names: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61333873/5382650

Comment: Or, the more conventional use of a section, groups all the symbols in a given range. You can then generate a table that has the start/end addresses for each section. When running, you could search for a symbol address within the table.

Comment: Very interesting, I'm not familiar with section attributes. I will surely further look into it!

Comment: Please tell me (at least by email) how many years of work can you afford spending. I believe that your time is the most critical resource.

Comment: Is your transpiler open source? If yes, provide an URL to its source code (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)...) in your question

Comment: “something that works universally” is impossible for a language that allows to convert a pointer to an `int` and back, without forbidding transformations of the `int` value, as long as they are reversible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typing information could be somehow encoded in the C function name; this is done by C++ and other implementations and called [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Actually, you could decide, since all your C code is generated, to adopt a different convention: generate long C identifiers which are practically unique and sort-of random program-wide, such as `tiziw_7oa7eIzzcxv03TmmZ` and keep their typing information elsewhere (e.g. some database). On Linux, such an approach is friendly to both [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace) and [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) + [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html) (and of course [nm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html) or [readelf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html) or [gdb(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html)), so used in both [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) and [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) projects.

Typing information is practically tied to [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) and [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)s. For example, the [x86-64 ABI for Linux](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf) mandates different [processor registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) for passing floating points or pointers.

Read the [Garbage Collection handbook](https://gchandbook.org/) or at least P.Wilson [*Uniprocessor Garbage Collection Techniques*](https://3e8.org/pub/pdf-t1/gcsurvey.pdf) survey. You could decide to use tagged integers instead of boxing them, and you could decide to have a conservative GC (e.g. [Boehm's GC](https://www.hboehm.info/gc/)) instead of a precise one. In my old [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) project I generated C or C++ code for a generational copying GC. Similar techniques are used both in [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) and in [RefPerSys](https://refpersys.org/).

Since you are transpiling to C, consider also alternatives, such as [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or [LLVM](http://llvm.org/). Look into [libjit](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/) and [asmjit](https://asmjit.com/).

Study also the implementation of other transpilers (compilers to C), including [Chicken/Scheme](https://www.call-cc.org/) and [Bigloo](https://www-sop.inria.fr/mimosa/fp/Bigloo/).

> Can the GCC compiler reorder the variables from how they're declared in the source code?

Of course yes, depending upon the optimizations you are asking. Some variables won't even exist in the binary (e.g. those staying in registers).

> Can I force the compiler to put some data in the method's stack frame (using volatile)?

Better generate a single `struct` variable containing all your language variables, and leave optimizations to the compiler. You will be surprised (see [this](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) draft report).

> Can I find the offset accurately when scanning the stack?

This is the most difficult, and depends *a lot* of [compiler optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (e.g. if you run `gcc`  with `-O1` or `-O3` on the generated C code; in *some* cases a recent GCC -e.g [GCC 9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/) or [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) on x86-64 for Linux- is capable of [tail-call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimizations; check by compiling using `gcc -O3 -S -fverbose-asm` then looking into the produced assembler code). If you accept some small target processor and compiler specific tricks, this is doable. Study the implementation of the [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/) compiler.

Send me (to `basile@starynkevitch.net`) an email for discussion. Please mention the URL of your question in it.

If you want to have an efficient generational copying GC with multi-threading, things become *extremely* tricky. The question is then how many years of development can you afford spending.

If you have exceptions in your language, take also a great care. You could with great caution generate calls to `longjmp`.

See of course [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065) of mine.

With transpiling techniques, **the evil is in the details**

On Linux (specifically!) see also my [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) program. It demonstrates that on a Linux x86-64 laptop you could generate, in practice, hundred of thousands of [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)-ed [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)). Read then [*How to write shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

Study also the implementation of [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/) and of [GNU Prolog](http://www.gprolog.org/), at least for inspiration.

PS. The dream of a totally architecture-neutral and operating-system independent transpiler is an illusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this extremely informative answer! Once I've read all the resources you've linked to, I will surely send you an email for further discussion. Have a good one!