# How can I hide the contents of a user-exposed C preprocessor definition in non-user code?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

In my C89 code, I have several units implementing a variety of abstract buffers which are to be treated by the user as if they were classes. That is, there is a public header defining the interfacing functions, and this is all the user ever sees. They are not intended to (need to) know what is going on behind the scenes.

However, at buffer creation, a raw byte-buffer is passed to the creation function, so the user must be able to know how much raw buffer space to allocate at compile time. This requires knowing how much space one item takes up in each abstract type. We are coding for a very limited embedded environment.

Currently, each buffer type has a private header in which a struct defines the format of the data. It is simple to add a macro for the size of the data element:

```
#define MY_ELEMENT_SIZE (sizeof(component_1_type) + sizeof(component_2_type))
```

However, `component_x_type` is intended to be hidden from the user, so this definition cannot go in the public header with the prototypes for the interfacing functions.

Our next idea was to have a `const` variable in the source:

```
const int MY_ELEMENT_SIZE = sizeof(component_1_type) + sizeof(component_2_type);
```

and an `extern` declaration in the public header:

```
extern const int MY_ELEMENT_SIZE;
```

But, because this is C89 and we have pedantry and MISRA and other requirements to fulfill, we cannot use variable-length arrays. In a "user" source file, to get a 50-element raw buffer, we write:

```
char rawBuffer[50 * MY_ELEMENT_SIZE] = {0u};
```

Using the `extern const...` method, this results in the compilation error:

```
error: variably modified ‘rawBuffer’ at file scope
```

This was not totally unexpected, but is disappointing in that `sizeof(any_type)` is genuinely constant and known at compile time.

Please advise me on how to expose the size of the data element in the public header without making the existence of `component_x_type` known to the user, in such a way that it can be used as an array length in C89.

Many, many thanks.

Comment: The most simple and stupid way that just works(TM): have a `#define MY_ELEMENT_SIZE 500` in the header and do `static_assert(MY_ELEMENT_SIZE == sizeof(component_1_type) + sizeof(component_2_type), "")` in the source.

Comment: Thanks! Useful info, no doubt, but I'm writing in C89, which does not have static assertions.

Comment: `does not have static assertions` [BUILD_BUG_ON](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/build_bug.h#L49)

Comment: How many millions of lines of C89 code do you deal with?

Comment: VLA would solve nothing since you provide an array initializer, and VLA can't have one.

Answer (score 0):

> In my C89 code

It is 2020 now. Discuss with your manager or client the opportunity to use a *less obsolete* [C standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)). In practice, most hand-written C89 code can be reasonably ported to C11, and you could use, buy or develop [code refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) tools -or services- helping you with that (e.g. your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html)). Remind to your manager or client that [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) has a lot of cost (probably dozen of thousands of US$ or €). Notice that old C89 compilers are in practice [optimizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) much less than recent ones, and that most junior developers (your future colleagues) are not even familiar with C89 (so they would need some kind of training, which costs a lot).

> How can I hide the contents of a user-exposed C preprocessor definition in non-user code?

As far as I know, you cannot (in theory). Check by reading the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Read also the documentation of [GNU cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) then of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (or of your C compiler).

> we have pedantry and MISRA and other requirements to fulfill

Be aware that these requirements have costs. Remind these costs to your client or manager.

---

<sup>(about hiding the content of a user-exposed C preprocessor `#define`)</sup>

However, in practice, a C code (e.g. inside some internal header file `#include`-d in your [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))) can be generated, and this is common practice (look into [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [SWIG](http://swig.org/) for a well known example of C code generator, and also consider using [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html) or [gpp](https://logological.org/gpp) or your own [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or [Python](https://python.org) script, or your own C or C++ program emitting C code). You simply have to configure your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) infrastructure (e.g. write [your `Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile)) for such a case.

If you have some script or utility generating things like `#define MACRO_7oa7eIzzcxv03Tm` (where `MACRO_7oa7eIzzcxv03Tm` is some pseudo-random or [name mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) identifier) then the probability of an accidental collision with client code is quite small. A human programmer is very unlikely to think of such identifiers, and with enough care a C generating script usually won't emit identifiers colliding with that. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61648572/841108) answer.

Perhaps your client or manager allows you to use (on your desktop) some generator of such "random-looking" identifier. AFAIK, they *are* MISRA compatible (but my MISRA standard is at office, and I am -may 2020- currently Covid19 confined at home, near Paris, France).

> we cannot use variable-length arrays.

You could (with approval from manager and client) consider using `struct`-s with [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) or else use arrays of dimension `0` or `1` as the last member of your `struct`-s. IIRC, that was common practice in SunOS3.2

Consider also using tools like [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/), [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), or -at end of 2020- my [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) coupled with a *recent* [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/). Think of subcontracting the [code review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_review) of your source code.

Comment: Flexible array members aren't very suitable for embedded systems, and explicitly banned by MISRA-C, because of the close relation between flex array members and dynamic allocation. Arrays with size 0 isn't standard C so that's even worse, as is using the old UB "struct hack" with size 1 items at the end.

Comment: It depends how you use them. The real issue is what memory allocation you have. [FreeRTOS](http://freertos.org/) provides something, and [Contiki](http://www.contiki-os.org/) something else.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the other answers, this is a quite *primitive* proposal. But it is easy to understand.

Since presumably you will not publish your header files too often to you clients, and so will not change the sizes of the types, you can use a (manually or automatically) calculated definition:

```
#define OUR_LIB_TYPE_X_SIZE 23
```

In your private sources you can then check the correctness of this assumption for example by

```
typedef char assert_type_x_has_size[2 * (sizeof (TypeX) == OUR_LIB_TYPE_X_SIZE) - 1];
```

It will error on any decent compiler on unequal sizes, because the array's size will be -1 and illegal. On equal sizes, the array's size is 1 and legal.

Because you're just defining a type, no code or memory is allocated. You might need to mark this as "unused" for some compilers or code checkers.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this very problem too - unfortunately private encapsulation also makes the object size encapsulated. Sometimes it is sufficient to simply return the object size through a getter function, but not always.

I solved it exactly as KamilCuk showed in comments: give the caller a raw "magic number" through a `#define` in the .h file, then a static assert inside the .c implementation checking that the define is consistent with the object size.

If that's not elegant enough, then perhaps you could consider outsourcing the size allocation to a run-time API from the "class":

```
uint8_t* component1_get_raw_buffer (size_t n);
```

Where you return a pointer to a statically allocated buffer inside the encapsulated "class". The caller code would then have to be changed to:

```
uint8_t* raw_buffer;
raw_buffer = component1_get_raw_buffer(50);
```

This involves some internal trickery keeping track of how much memory that's allocated (and error handling - maybe return NULL on failure). You will to reserve a fixed maximum size for the internal static buffer, to cover the worst use-case scenario.

(Optionally: `const` qualify the returned pointer if the user isn't supposed to modify the data)

Advantages are: better OO design, no heap allocation, remain MISRA-C compliant. Disadvantages are function call overhead during initialization and the need to set aside "enough" memory in advance.

Also, this method isn't very safe in a multi-threading environment, but that's not usually an issue in embedded systems.